# Is there a way to make an "if" inside another if"

Tags: java, if-statement

How do I make it so that if the username is incorrect, it doesn't ask for the password but immediately says that the username is incorrect?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SecurityPasscode
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Enter Username");

        String username;
        username = user_input.next();

        if (username.equals("username"))
            System.out.println("Enter Password");

        String password;
        password = user_input.next();

        if (password.equals("password"))
            System.out.println("Welcome back " + username + "!");

        if (!"password".equals(password))
            System.out.println("That password is incorrect.");
        else if (!"username".equals(username))
            System.out.println("That username is incorrect.");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `{` after your first `if`....

Note that these two blocks of code are **not** the same:

```
if(something1)
  command1;
  command2;
  if(something2)
    command3;
else if(something3)
```

---

```
if(something1) {
  command1;
  command2;
  if(something2)
    command3;
}
else if(something3)
```

In the first code, the `else` corresponds to the **last** if. In the second code, it corresponds to the **first** `if`. Furthermore, in the first code, `command2` is not in the scope of the external `if` because Java doesn't really cares about indentation..

Answer (score 1):

```
if (username.equals("username")){
    System.out.println("Enter Password");
}else{
    String password;
    password = user_input.next();
    if (password.equals("password")){
        System.out.println("Welcome back " + username + "!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("That password is incorrect.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (condition)
{
    if (another condition)
    {
        // statements here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes...

```
if(eval)
    if(anotherEval)
       ....
          code
```

you could have any number of nested if as you like :)